# How to unrar bundles with unrar lib

Tags: objective-c, unrar

I use **unrar** lib on Mac OS. I can't unrar bundles inside archive. I have a bundle - Mybundle.component inside the archive. During extracting the files I come across, say, the file like

```
MyArchive/Mybudle.component/Contents/myfile.file
```

which I need to place by path

```
/Users/MyUser/Unarchived/Mybudle.component/Contents/myfile.file
```

For this purpose I use RARProcessFile. It works if /Users/MyUser/Unarchived/Mybudle.component exists. How can I "extract bundle"?

Comment: What is what you call "unrar lib"?  Is it the command-line tool offered at the RAR download web site?  What's obvious to you is not obvious to others, at least not to the ignorant including me.  Please be clear about keywords that you use.

Comment: That's what I mean - http://www.rarlab.com/rar_add.htm

Comment: Some people just don't get it.